# No such File or directory exception Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, file-handling

In my application I am getting images and video files from document directory and through intent and then getting absolute path in `OnActivityResult()` method where request code matches 2 and then there is an `AsyncTask` responsible for sending on of the file(for testing purpose to server) but it catches exception in `doPlaceUpload()` method inside `doInBackground()`

**Exception :**
 `/document/image:1665: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

I think I am unable to get files from absolute path but as I am new to android so I am unable to figure out how to do that.

**Code:**

```
public class AddPlaceActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Button addMap,selectFiles;
    ImageView uploadBtn;
    TextView placeName,placeDesc;
    double lat;
    double lng;
    String FilePath;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    HttpEntity resEntity;
    ArrayList<String> FileNames=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<File> FilesToUpload=new ArrayList<File>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_place);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        init_views();
    }

private void init_views(){
    uploadBtn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.place_uplaod_btn);
    addMap = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_map_place);
    selectFiles = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_files);

    //Listeners
    uploadBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new PostTask().execute("http://www.petrichors.com/eguide/upload_media_test.php");
        }
    });
    selectFiles.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openGallery(2);
        }
    });
    addMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(AddPlaceActivity.this,AddPlaceMap.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent,1);
        }
    });
}
    public void openGallery(int req_code){

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        String[] mimetypes = {"image/*", "video/*"};
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
        startActivityForResult(intent, req_code);

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_add_place, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // Call Back method  to get the Message form Map Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if(requestCode==1)
        {
           // String message=data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");
            lat = data.getDoubleExtra("Lat",0.0);
            lng = data.getDoubleExtra("Lng",0.0);
            //show();


        }

            //
            if (requestCode == 2)
            {
                Uri selectedFileUri = data.getData();
                File myFile = new File(selectedFileUri.getPath());
               FilesToUpload.add(myFile);

            }

        }
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    private void show(){
         Toast.makeText(this, lat + " : " + lng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    // The definition of our task class
    private class PostTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Log.i("Async : ","PRe Exec");
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AddPlaceActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // for debug worker thread
            if(android.os.Debug.isDebuggerConnected())
                android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();

            Log.i("Async : ","Do back");
            String url=params[0];
            doPlaceUpload(url);

            return "All Done!";
        }

        //Upload Function
        private void doPlaceUpload(String Url){
            Log.i("Async : ","Do placeUpload");
            String urlString = Url;
            try
            {

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlString);
                FileBody bin1 = new FileBody(FilesToUpload.get(0));
                MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
                reqEntity.addPart("uploadedfile1", bin1);
                reqEntity.addPart("user", new StringBody("User"));
                post.setEntity(reqEntity);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                resEntity = response.getEntity();
                final String response_str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
                if (resEntity != null) {
                    Log.i("RESPONSE",response_str);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        public void run() {
                            try {
//                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response_str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                String ExceptionString = ex.getMessage();
                Log.e("Debug", "UploadError: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);

            }
        }


        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            Log.i("Async : ","P-UPDATE");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.i("Async : ","POSt Exec");
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }
}
```

My question is how should I get a File from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and save them in ArrayList as in my case `FilesToUpload` As the document may contain Videos as well as Images how to handle them respectively.

Comment: not a file: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT

Comment: @njzk2 sorry I didnt get it

Comment: the result you are getting is not a file. I don't know why you would assume that.

Comment: @njzk2 I got it but how do I get File from it as it may contain Image or video how to treat them seperatly?

Answer (score 0):

> I think I am unable to get files from absolute path

There is no "absolute path". `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` does not open a file. It opens a piece of content. That content is represented by the `Uri` that you get back in `onActivityResult()`. [The documentation for the Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html#open-client) shows you how to use that `Uri`, such as using a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`.

See also:

- ["The Storage Access Framework FAQ"](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/05/03/storage-access-framework-faq.html)
- ["How to Consume Content from a `Uri`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html)